# Expected number of parts of a uniformly selected partition of $n$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, probability-theory, integer-partitions

I have a very basic question on partition theory, which I feel should be very well known. Suppose that you fix a natural number $n$ and select a random partition $P$ of $n$ by choosing uniformly from the set of all partitions of $n$ (so that each partition has probability $\frac{1}{p(n)}$ of being selected, where $p(n)$ stands for the number of partitions of $n$).  My question is that, **what is the best known estimate/approximation of the expected number of parts of $P$ and the length of the largest part of $P$?**

Since the there is an inherent symmetry between the number of parts and the length of the largest part of a partition (which is more clear if one views the Young's diagram), and since the area of the Young's diagram is $n$, I suspect that the expectation is roughly of the order of $\sqrt{n}$, although this is a heuristic guess. Can anyone give me the best known estimate?

Comment: An asymptotic formula is known: $\sqrt{\frac{3n}{2\pi}}(\log n+2\gamma-\log\tfrac{\pi}6)+{\rm{O}}(\log^3 n)$. Source: http://resolver.sub.uni-goettingen.de/purl?PPN362162050_0081

Comment: Thanks, Andrew!