# Expected Value for the Number of Parts of a Partition of n

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, integer-partitions

Given a positive integer $n$, I want to know the expected value for the number of parts of a random partition of $n$.

I am aware that a similar question has been asked already: [Expected number of parts of a uniformly selected partition of $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3004510/expected-number-of-parts-of-a-uniformly-selected-partition-of-n) ; however, I do not want to select the partitions uniformly. I want to collect the partitions of $n$ and have the partition $\lambda$ appear $dim(\lambda)$ times. For example, for $n=3$ we have

$\{3\}$ (once)

$\{2,1\}$ (twice)

$\{1,1,1\}$ (once)

So the expected value will be $\frac{1+2+2+3}{4}=2.$

I wrote some code to compute this and it looks like the function is logarithmic in $n$, which is the case in the linked question, too. How is my question related to uniform case? Are there any known results for this?

Thank you

Comment: Have you plugged the first 10 or so values into the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/)? Does $\dim \lambda$ mean the number of standard tableaux of shape $\lambda$ ?

Comment: @darijgrinberg Not all of the expected values are integers. And yes, by the dimension I mean the number of different standard Young tableaux of shape $\lambda$.

Comment: The OEIS would likely have the expected value times $n!$.

Comment: Ah, wait. Not times $n! $ but times the number of all standard Young tableaux of size $n $.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thank you for the suggestion. The first couple of terms are 1,3,8,24,73,239,809... Unfortunately the OEIS doesn't have this sequence.

Comment: Interesting -- it's probably worth adding if you can find out anything about it or have a good motivation. All I can suggest is to use Schur-Weyl duality: If you can find an endomorphism $f$ of a vector space $V$ such that the trace of $f$ acting on the $\lambda$-Schur functor of $V$ is $\ell\left(\lambda\right)$ (that is, the number of parts of $\lambda$) for each $\lambda \vdash n$, then $\sum\limits_{\lambda \vdash n} \left(\dim \lambda\right) \ell\left(\lambda\right)$ is the trace of $f$ acting on $V^{\otimes n}$. Remains to find such an $f$, of course.